# Microsoft Bot framework SDK V4

Tags: botframework

How can we migrate SDK V3 to SDK V4 Logging of user and bot in Microsoft Bot framework C# SDK V4 using core Bot?

Comment: You need to do manually because in V4 have it's own activity handler, Ibot,etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-framework?view=azure-bot-service-4.0